# magento: how to set different languages between front-end and back-end

Tags: magento

I built one magento site with some language packs. now I want to show English at front-end pages,  at the same time, show Spanish at admin page. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For admin english,

Set the default config scope,

```
system > config > (general) general > local options > locale > english (US)
```

be sure to set that at the "default config" scope, and log out and then in to be taken into account